# IntelliJ inspections: convert package.html to package-info.java

Tags: intellij-idea

Apparently, in Intellij 10, a new feature was intriduced to automatically convert package.html to package-info.java files. I have 11 and 12 and can't find it.

Here's the feature: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64769

I had the "Inspection Gadgets" plugin active already.

And have enabled the Javadoc issues inspection for it.

When I open package.html files they're green, no yellow warning appears. How do i trigger the conversion? What am I missing?

I have 2 nice screenshot images for the settings, but stackoverflow does not let me post them because I only hvae 10 reputation points.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug, I was able to reproduce the problem and [reported it in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99479), please star/vote to receive notifications on the issue progress.

Comment: Since CrazyCoder is from the JetBrains team this is the definite answer for now.